# How to set Open DNS settings on router Tp-Link ARCHER MR600 with a 4G network?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, router

I'm  trying to use *OpenDNS* to make my network safer. I use a *TP-Link ARCHER MR600* which is a 4G modem  router (I have a Sim Card inside it, I'm not on Adsl).

I created my account on *OpenDSN.com* but when I try to add my network [here](https://dashboard.opendns.com/settings/) I'm told that

> "you cannot add a network in private  IP space"

The IP Address I entered was under the section *Internet* in the *Basic* -> *Network Map* page (see image 1)-->

[image: image 1 - IP Address in the Network Map]

I also entered the following command in the command line, by following a thread (what is this for?):

```
nslookup -type=txt debug.opendns.com
```

and I got the following output (I override the possible sensitive info with a custom message between < > ):

```
    Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.202.0.1

opendns.com
        primary name server = auth1.opendns.com
        responsible mail addr = noc.opendns.com
        serial  = <a set of 10 number here>
        refresh = 16384 (4 hours 33 mins 4 secs)
        retry   = 2048 (34 mins 8 secs)
        expire  = 1048576 (12 days 3 hours 16 mins 16 secs)
        default TTL = 2560 (42 mins 40 secs)

C:\Users\myUserName>nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  <here there are 4 sequences of numbers separated by comma, like "00.000.0.0">
```

I  also tried to change the DNS manually, but I noticed that my router control panel is missing the *WAN* section under the NETWORK Page, therefore I entered the *LAN settings* and found *Primary DNS* and *Secondary DNS* there, see image 2:

[image: image 2 - DNS in LAN settings]

As I can edit them, I substituted the 0.0.0.0. by entering some others indicated in the OpenDNS page, I saved and rebooted. But I still saw the old *DNS server* in the Network Map section (see image 1), so I reset to the factory settings.

I can't  figure out where I should go in order to set Open DNS:

1. Should I change DNS manually from the router control panel? In this case, why do I see two different places with different DNS values and which one should I focused on? In any case, I can't edit the DNS server in the *Network Map* (see image 1) and I miss the WAN section under "Network".
2. Should I change them from the *OpenDNS web page*? If yes, why I'm told that the IP is private? Did I add the wrong one or it's a problem related to 4G modem routers or something else?
3. What the `nslookup -type=txt debug.opendns.com` does and what does the output above mean?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I change DNS manually from the router control panel? In this
> case, why do I see two different places with different DNS values and
> which one should I focused on? In any case, I can't edit the DNS
> server in the Network Map (see image 1) and I miss the WAN section
> under "Network".

I have the same router, in 4G mode you cannot alter the WAN settings, these are set by your carrier. You can only alter the LAN DHCP DNS servers. Add DNS Servers in Advanced -> Network -> LAN Settings.

You can wait for your Tablet/PC to update or clear the DNS cache `CMD -> ipconfig /flushdns`

Verify the new DNS settings using `CMD -> ipconfig /all`

[CMD prompt & tp-link router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6cZk.png)

> Should I change them from the OpenDNS web page? If yes, why I'm told
> that the IP is private? Did I add the wrong one or it's a problem
> related to 4G modem routers or something else?

When you are registering, you telling OpenDNS that it's you. As you are inside your network the IP address may be a local address e.g. 192.168.x.x or 10.0.x.x.
You can use the Dynamic Updater tools to update OpenDNS with your Dynamic IP https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227987867-What-is-the-OpenDNS-Dynamic-IP-updater-client-

> What the nslookup -type=txt debug.opendns.com does and what does the
> output above mean?

NSLOOKUP is **N**ame **S**erver **LOOKUP**, this command is querying DNS and returning the results it finds for (type=txt) txt entries for debug.opendns.com
See: https://support.umbrella.com/hc/en-us/articles/230903828-How-To-Determine-Which-Policy-Is-Being-Applied-In-My-Umbrella-Configuration

Typing NSLOOKUP will start the tool in interactive mode, it will tell you what it's using for the DNS lookups and then you can entry subsequent commands. Good guide here: https://www.ionos.co.uk/digitalguide/server/tools/nslookup/

If you want to secure your home internet I'd suggest using DNS over http (can be done in the browser) or get the app at https://cloudflare-dns.com/

If you're feeling up to a wee project, set up a https://pi-hole.net/